# Spliting up a single pdf page

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-vista

I have a pdf file (which is an ebook),each page of pdf have two pages of the actual (hardcopy) of the book,for example this is how a single pdf page looks like:

[image]

Now,my problem is when i am trying to take the print out,only  the page toward left is printed(the page 14 for this example),this is same for every other pdf pages in this ebook.

So my question how to  to take the print out of all pages of this kind of file?I tried using pdf to word convertor but it doesn't working for this kind of file.

**PS:** I am windows user, so I would appreciate windows specific solutions.

Comment: Silly question, but did you try printing in landscape?

Comment: @Kev:Yes I did but it's not working for me,but I still couldn't understand what is silly about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/ will help you crop the pages. By the way, printing the whole pages is easier: You can select to resize the (double) page to fit the paper in the print settings:
in adobe acrobat reader:

Section *"Page Handling"* - *"Page Scaling"*: select *"Shrink to printable area"*

and in your case, open the printer properties using the button labeled "properties" and select landscape as page orientation.

other pdf viewers will propably have similar options.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by k2pdfopt as well:

```
k2pdfopt -grid 2x1x0 -w .5s -h 1s file.pdf
```

This will split each page into two, and the output, file_k2opt.pdf, will have twice as many pages.

http://willus.com/k2pdfopt

Answer (score 0):

All you have make a copy of the document, then crop (twice) its not ideal, but it works (may require adobe acrobat, and cannot be done in reader). If you do not care about the fact that its text or similar, then you can also use printscreen.